# Operator overloading of new operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the following code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size);
    void operator delete(void*);
    Test() { cout<<"\n Constructor called"; }
    ~Test() { cout<<"\n Destructor called"; }
};

void* Test::operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout<<"\n new called";
    void *storage = malloc(size);
    return storage;
}

void Test::operator delete(void *p )
{
    cout<<"\n delete called";
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    Test *m = new Test();
    delete m;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
new called
 Constructor called
 Destructor called
 delete called
```

However, when I called the new operator I didn't specify the size to be allocated to the object, neither I used any default value for the size. Can someone explain how much memory would be allocated for the object and why?

Comment: Don't mix `new` and `operator new`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation: *When calling the allocation function, the `new`-expression passes the number of bytes requested as the first argument, of type `std::size_t`, which is exactly `sizeof(T)` for non-array `T`.*

Answer (score 7):

`operator new` is passed the size that C++ determines is needed for the allocation.

It is not what you are calling directly when you call `new Test()` - rather, the language converts that (very) roughly into:

```
void* tmp = Test::operator new(sizeof(Test));
Test* result = ::new(tmp) Test();
```

the first line above allocates memory.  The second constructs a `Test` in that memory; it is called "placement new".

The fact that both constructing and getting memory is called `new` is confusing, but true.

(The real equivalent code to what the complier does with `new Test()` handles construction failure, follows more complex lookup rules, etc).